# Place process in background with find+xargs+nohup

Tags: bash, xargs, nohup

Where do I add `nohup` and `&` to put this in the  background?
I tried multiple places and had no luck.

```sh
find . -links 2  -type d |
xargs -I{} -P 5 -n 1  bash -c 'cd "{}" && run_script.sh'
```

Comment: `bash -c 'cd "{}"...` will break on `"`, Use arguments - `xargs -n1 bash -c 'cd "$1"' --`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer - just put it at the end of the line.

```
find . -links 2 -type d | xargs -I{} -P 5 -n 1 bash -c 'cd "{}" && run_script.sh' &
```

That effectively puts the pipeline in background.
You're probably going to want to manage your i/o though.

Comment: `-P 5-n` should probably be `-P 5 -n`. You can put the `nohup` in front of the `find`.

Comment: Yeah, I had to fix that in my test and forgot to fix it here. Thanks.

Comment: run_script.sh is long running process. It is terminating even if find is in the background

Comment: maybe what you need is `cd "{}" && nohup run_script.sh &'. That will thow a `nohup.out` in every directory, but your output (if any) will be clearly associated with the relevant location. You could manage your own redirections if you wanted. Make sure here is useful logging, even if it's just turning on debug mode with `set -x` inside `run_script.sh`.